# Java com Spring Boot retornando "malformed payload" ao autenticar token JWT gerado pelo Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Olá!

Estou com um problema em uma API Rest Java com Spring Boot onde existe autenticação via token JWT.

A versão do Java é a 17 e a do Spring Boot é a 3.0.0.

Os tokens são gerados no Keycloak e faço uso de multitenancy para o acesso dos clientes no banco de dados. O problema que enfrento é o seguinte:
quando um token gerado com ClientId e SecretId é enviado, a API consegue autenticar sem problemas, dando o acesso ou bloqueando quando necessário.

Agora quando um token gerado sem o SecretId (apenas com o ClientId) é enviado, a API retorna 401 e a informação que retorna no header WWW-Authenticate é a seguinte:

"Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed payload", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"".

Eu já verifiquei o token no "jwt.io" e não há problemas no token gerado.

Estou seguindo as [instruções do próprio Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/docs/modules/ROOT/pages/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.adoc) para fazer a verificação.

Mesmo com o link, vou deixar o código aqui:

- Classe que faz a seleção do token:

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.exemplo.multitenancy.config.configuracaoAutenticacao.reposirotires"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "configuracaoAutenticacaoEntityManagerFactory")
public class TenantJWSKeySelector implements JWTClaimsSetAwareJWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> {

    @Autowired
    ConfiguracaoAutenticacaoRepository configuracaoAutenticacaoRepository;
    private final Map<String, JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext>> selectors = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    public TenantJWSKeySelector(ConfiguracaoAutenticacaoRepository configuracaoAutenticacaoRepository) {
        this.configuracaoAutenticacaoRepository = configuracaoAutenticacaoRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<? extends Key> selectKeys(JWSHeader jwsHeader, JWTClaimsSet jwtClaimsSet,
                                          SecurityContext securityContext)
            throws KeySourceException {
        return this.selectors.computeIfAbsent(toTenant(jwtClaimsSet), this::fromTenant)
                .selectJWSKeys(jwsHeader, securityContext);
    }

    private String toTenant(JWTClaimsSet claimSet) {
        return (String) claimSet.getClaim("iss");
    }

    private JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> fromTenant(String tenant) {

        var split = tenant.split("/", 6);
        var cliente_id = split[5];

        var selector = this.configuracaoAutenticacaoRepository.findByClienteId(cliente_id)
                .map(ConfiguracaoAutenticacao::getJwks_uri)
                .map(this::fromUri)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Tenant errado na seleção"));

        return selector;
    }

    private JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> fromUri(String uri) {
        try {
            var valor = JWSAlgorithmFamilyJWSKeySelector.fromJWKSetURL(new URL(uri));
            return valor;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    JWTProcessor jwtProcessor(JWTClaimsSetAwareJWSKeySelector keySelector) {
        ConfigurableJWTProcessor<SecurityContext> jwtProcessor = new DefaultJWTProcessor();
        jwtProcessor.setJWTClaimsSetAwareJWSKeySelector(keySelector);
        return jwtProcessor;
    }
}
```

- Classe que faz a verificação do token:

```
@Component
public class TenantJwtIssuerValidator implements OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> {

    @Autowired
    private final ConfiguracaoAutenticacaoRepository tenants;

    private final OAuth2Error error = new OAuth2Error(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_TOKEN, "The iss claim is not valid",
            "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1");

    public TenantJwtIssuerValidator(ConfiguracaoAutenticacaoRepository tenants) {
        this.tenants = tenants;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt token) {
        if (this.tenants.findByClienteId(toTenant(token)) != null) {
            var resposta = OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
            return resposta;
        }
        return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(this.error);
    }

    private String toTenant(Jwt jwt) {
        return jwt.getIssuer().toString();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWTProcessor jwtProcessor, OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> jwtValidator) {
        NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = new NimbusJwtDecoder(jwtProcessor);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> validator = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(JwtValidators.createDefault(),
                jwtValidator);
        decoder.setJwtValidator(validator);
        return decoder;
    }
}
```

Eu já procurei a resposta em vários lugares, porém nada me ajudou. Alguém tem alguma sugestão sobre qual pode ser o problema?

Esse é o primeiro post que faço, então se faltar alguma informação por favor me avisem.

Agradeço a atenção desde já!